# Using a simple code in Fortran structure ( DO & IF)

Tags: if-statement, fortran, do-loops

I want to use the if (....) then and elseif (....) then in a Do loop. However, I am not sure about the structure and its possibilities. Could anyone please help me with this simple code?

```
      Do i=0,1000,1
          T(i)=t-(i*TI)
          if (z(i) .EQ. 0.00) then
              z(i+1)=v*T(i)
          elseif (z(i) .EQ. A) then
              z(i+1)=A-v*T(i)
          endif   
          r1=sqrt(x**2+(z-z(i))**2)
          flux(1)=((alpha*p)/(d*pi*r0**2))*exp(-(r1**2/r0**2))
          flux(2)=0 
      end do
```

Comment: The possibilities are... infinite :D . Seriously, what do you mean by "possibilities"? Same as any other IF in any other programming language, I'd say

Comment: Please do not put Fortran code into HTML snippets. Pleace make your question more specific otherwise I have to vote to close as "**Needs more focus** *This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*" Is there actual problem you are facing with the code you are showing? Some error message? Or wrong result? Which one exactly? See [ask].

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I want to use this code in the Abaqus subroutine which should be in Fortran structure, and I am not sure: 1- is it possible to use if and else if in a do loop? 2- my code is correct or not? It doesn't work for now! and I don't know why.

Comment: @VladimirF it is the first time I am asking the question here. The main problem is related to the code itself. I am not sure it is correct or not regarding Fortran structure.

Comment: There is no obvious syntax error visible, but I have no idea whether it does what you want it to do. Is there any particular problem that made you to ask this question?

Comment: I don't know anything about Fortran, so I can only help you with question #1: yes, you can be sure that you can use an IF inside a DO, there is no reason to disallow it. Regarding question #2, you'll have to be more specific: _why_ doesn't it work, what's the error that you're getting, what is the input data that you're using to test it, what are the expected results? There are many variables in the code that we don't know; for instance, what is alpha, z, A, etc.? you should post a piece of code that allows anyone to reproduce the problem, in its current state we can't answer your question

Comment: @VladimirF it is a subroutine that I used In Abaqus. when It works, the simulation starts and when it is wrong, the simulation doesn't run. There is no error for displaying.

Comment: So, with the full code you show, is there any problem or not? Does the simulation run or not? Do you get the results you want to get or not? Please try to be clearer. Be aware that you are indexing `z` and `t` as arrays, but you did not define them as arrays. You need to define their dimension.

Comment: As a completely tangential note: `pi=3.1416` is really bad, try `pi=acos(1.d0)` (no neet to respond)

Comment: @VladimirF The code doesn't lead to run the simulation and it means there is something wrong with the syntax (spaces, punctuation,...) or logic.

Comment: Let's repeat the important in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indexing `z` and `T` as arrays like this:

`T(i)`  `z(i)`

but you did not define them as arrays. You must declare their dimension somehow.

The compiler should complain in some way, saying that you use them as functions in a improper way or some similar related error message.

After fixing that try to follow the logic of the loop checking that you properly defined the initial values and the other values are computed using the preceding values.

---

You should also definitely add `IMPLICIT NONE` at the top of your subroutine.

Comment: T(i) and z(i) are not arrays. They are just integer like this z(0)=0.00, z(1)=0.07....

Comment: But that means that `z` and `T` must be arrays and the elements of these arrays are your numbers. I think you will need to look at some introductory text about arrays in Fortran.

Comment: How do you know `T` and `z` are not declared as arrays?  Without seeing `ABA_PARAM.INC` it would seem to be impossible to know whether `T` and `z` are functions rather than arrays.

Comment: @francescalus I do not think Abaqus uses such one-letter variables in the API and only defines the dimension, not the type. That would make the include file incompatible with other `IMPLICIT` choices people could make when including it. The variables available are mentioned in https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEANLRefMap/simaanl-c-subroutineover.htm#simaanl-c-subroutineover-sol-dep-var Notably, the OP clearly tries to define `z` and `T` himself.

Comment: @francescalus And they definitely aren't functions, Masud clearly says they are numbers in the above comment.

Comment: They may not be intended to be functions, but that's how they are (/appear to be) declared.  If `aba_param.inc` has `dimension z(506)`, say, then they are arrays, and functions otherwise.  Does `aba_param.inc` have such a dimension statetement?  No idea, probably not, but it may.

Comment: @francescalus Almost surely not. I did write "The compiler should complain in some way, saying that you use them **as functions** in a improper way or some similar related error message." Note that they are also used on the left side of the assignment. That's why I concluded they shall be declared to be arrays.

Comment: "but you did not define them as arrays." I submit that we do not know that the user did not define them as arrays. I agree that the intention is for them to be used as arrays, and that they should be declared as arrays, and that the compiler will be quite explicit in complaining if they are not. But I think it's also quite possible that they have been declared as arrays and it's impossible to tell from the question as it is.

Comment: The inclide file is not some random file we cannot see. It describes the API to Abaqus user subroutines as described in the link. There is no `t(506)` in there. I cannot say it 100%, but 99.99% should be enough.